# full page image with animated transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, css-transitions

I am trying to make a fade in- fade out transition between two pages with full screen images. Currently I'm trying to achieve this with the swup plugin.

I can achieve a new full screen image on each page by setting a class on every html, like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" class="home_bg">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="/about.html">About</a>
    </nav>   
</body>
</html>
```

And css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.home_bg {
    background: url(img/landscape.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.about_bg {
    background: url(img/ocean.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
nav{
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Html for the transition:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script defer src="node_modules/swup/dist/swup.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="/about.html">About</a>
    </nav>   
    <main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
        <h1>This is home</h1>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav{
    font-size: 24px;
}

.transition-fade{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 500ms;
}  
html.is-animating .transition-fade {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

There is also one line js for the transition:

```
const swup = new Swup();
```

My problem is I can't seem to get these two to work together. I either get the full image pages OR the transition, not the full image pages WITH transition. The problem seems to lie in the fact that the image has to be within the "swup". But every time I try to put my image there, I lose control over its size and proportions, even if I give it a class of its own.

Now I have tried about a zillion things and I have tried to google this for a few days but no luck. I have only been working with html, css and js with this. Should I be looking elsewhere?

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hi, could you make [mre] using js fiddle?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this. It may not be the best solution, so if you have a better one, please let us know.

I added this html-part below the navigationbar:

```
<main id="swup" class="transition-fade">
        <div class="background-parent">
            <div class="background-home"></div>         
        </div>
</main>
```

And in the css:

```
.background-home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(img/landscape.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```